# How to check if the date is included in holidays?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i want to exclude the holiday dates from two selected dates ,
i have write the code , by checking if the range between start date and end date is included in holiday array then make the total days -1 . but is not working , so how i can do it

this is my code

```
 const workday_count = (start: moment.Moment, end: moment.Moment, publicHolidays: Date[]) => {
  const first = start.clone().endOf('week');
  const last = end.clone().startOf('week');
  const days = (last.diff(first, 'days') * 5) / 7;
  let wfirst = first.day() - start.day();
  const sta = start.toDate();
  const en = end.toDate();
  const range = enumerateDaysBetweenDates(sta, en);

  if (start.day() === 6) --wfirst;
  let wlast = end.day() - last.day();
  if (end.day() === 5) --wlast;

  const withOutWeekend = wfirst + Math.floor(days) + wlast;
  const count = 0;

  range.forEach((date) => {
    if (publicHolidays.includes(date)) {
      return count + 1;
    }
  });

  return withOutWeekend;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. it seems publicHolidays.includes(date) will always return false, so you can try publicHolidays.find() to check if date in this range
2. when the start day is Sunday(start.day() === 0), your wfirst would be 5 instead of 6
3. when the end day is Saturday(end.day() === 6), your wlast would be 5 instead of 6

Here is the code:

```
const workday_count = (start, end, publicHolidays) => {
  const first = start.clone().endOf("week");
  const last = end.clone().startOf("week");
  const days = (last.diff(first, "days") * 5) / 7;

  let wfirst = first.day() - start.day();
  // when start is Sunday
  if (start.day() === 0) --wfirst;
  let wlast = end.day() - last.day();
  // when end is Saturday
  if (end.day() === 6) --wlast;

  const sta = start.toDate();
  const en = end.toDate();
  const range = enumerateDaysBetweenDates(sta, en);

  let withOutWeekend = wfirst + Math.floor(days) + wlast;
  let count = 0;

  range.forEach((date) => {
    // check if the date is in publicHolidays
    if (
      publicHolidays.find((holiday) => holiday.getTime() === date.getTime())
    ) {
      count++;
    }
  });
  
  return withOutWeekend - count;
};
```

BTW, I think you can describe more detailed in your question about how is your code not working, so that we can have a better understanding of the problem. :)

Comment: To explain further, dates are objects, and objects are compared by identity (i.e. objects are only equal to themselves). Just like `({}) === ({})` is `false`, `new Date(2021, 8, 30) === new Date(2021, 8, 30)` is `false`. As Jane shows, comparing the seconds since epoch (`.getTime()`), an integer, gives you the correct answer.